# htaccess : virtual subdomain mapping to folder

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to point random sub domain to the folder named as sub domain...For example if i have sub domain `random123.domain.com` it should point to the folder `random123`.If folder not found it must throw 404 error . I tried below code but its not working,some one please guide me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).domain.com
RewriteRule ^$ /%1/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (mod_proxy and mod_rewrite should be enabled):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+).domain.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+).domain.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 !-d
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: hi , i used urs ,but i always get server not found. what is the problem ?